# How to convert an Objective-C Block into a Swift Closure?

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have the following Objective-C block assignment example from Github [dzenbot/DZNPhotoPickerController](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNPhotoPickerController/blob/master/Examples/PhotoEditor/PhotoEditor/ViewController.m) that I am struggling to convert to Swift. Controller is a UIImagePickerController.

```
controller.finalizationBlock = ^(UIImagePickerController *picker, NSDictionary *info) {

    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    weakSelf.imageView.image = image;

    // Dismiss when the crop mode was disabled
    if (picker.cropMode == DZNPhotoEditorViewControllerCropModeNone) {
        [weakSelf dismissController:picker];
    }
};
```

I have tried the following, but cannot figure out where I am going wrong.

```
controller.finalizationBlock = { (picker: UIImagePickerController, info: NSDictionary) -> UIImagePickerControllerFinalizationBlock! in
        var image = UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage(info)
        imageView.image = image

        // Dismiss when the crop mode was disabled
        if (picker.cropMode == .None) {
            dismissEditor(picker)
        }
    }
```

The error I get is:

> "Cannot assign value of type '(UIImagePickerController, NSDictionary) -> UIImagePickerControllerFinalizationBlock!' to type 'UIImagePickerControllerFinalizationBlock!'

Comment: try to use [This](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/) website for basic Obj-c to Swift conversion

Comment: yeah sometimes it just does not produce the exact expected result but i think it because Swift is channg quickly. So hopefully the site will update accordingly in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Objective-C block does not return anything, so the closure for the same should look like this:

```
controller.finalizationBlock = { (picker, info) in
        var image = UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage(info)
        imageView.image = image

        // Dismiss when the crop mode was disabled
        if (picker.cropMode == .None) {
            dismissEditor(picker)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I now get a similar error: "Cannot assign value of type '(UIImagePickerController, NSDictionary) -> ()' to type 'UIImagePickerControllerFinalizationBlock!'

Comment: Thanks ZeMoon, the (picker, info) set me on the correct path. Would you mind explaining what was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Objective-C block returns nothing,

```
controller.finalizationBlock = { (picker: UIImagePickerController, info: NSDictionary) -> (Void) in
        var image = UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage(info)
        imageView.image = image

        // Dismiss when the crop mode was disabled
        if (picker.cropMode == .None) {
            dismissEditor(picker)
        }
    }
```

Note 1. If you're going to use the closure in other functions you can declare an Alias in order to provides more readable code (But It's not mandatory)

```
typealias UIImagePickerControllerFinalizationBlock = (picker: UIImagePickerController, info: NSDictionary) -> (Void)
```

Note 2. Maybe you can make the info parameter type more "*Swifty*" with `[String: AnyObject]` or whatever the type info parameter uses.

Comment: I now get a similar error: "Cannot assign value of type '(UIImagePickerController, NSDictionary) -> (Void)' to type 'UIImagePickerControllerFinalizationBlock!'

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help you :

```
controller.finalizationBlock = {(picker: UIImagePickerController, info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> Void in
     var image: UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]
     weakSelf.imageView.image = image
    // Dismiss when the crop mode was disabled
     if picker.cropMode == DZNPhotoEditorViewControllerCropMode.None 
     {
         weakSelf.dismissController(picker)
     }
}
```